# How to add customized typing indicator using c# in Azure bot

Tags: asp.net-core, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I am building a chat application using botframework v4 with .net core. I want to implement customized typing indicator. Currently I am using below code and it is showing typing indicator like below image

```
    public async override Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ITypingActivity replyActivity = Activity.CreateTypingActivity(); 
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync((Activity)replyActivity); 
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    }
```

output:
[image]

But instead of showing this typing symbol(...), I need to show some customized message (like bot is typing) and after getting bot response indicator need to remove automatically.

Comment: What channels are you wanting to do this for? Just for bot framework Web Chat?

Comment: Yes, I am using direct line connection

Answer (score 0):

Using WebChat, there's not a *built-in* way to easily customize the typing indicator. But you should be able to modify the css. I would start with some investigation [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/02.branding-styling-and-customization).

If you are wanting to do this for *more than* just WebChat, that might not be possible. Instead of using typing activities, you might be able to use [proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to accomplish the goal.